# What could be the best solution to avoid the conflict of http and https popups in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, https, popup

What could be the best solution to avoid the conflict of http and https popups in IE? 
I have many Secured connection pages where i face this popup in IE, I want to handle it how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relative URLs where possible, you can even have [protocol relative URLs](http://www.stringify.com/2008/feb/27/relative/):

```
<img src="/myimg.png" alt="This domain" />
<img src="//www.myotherdomain.com/myimg.png" alt="Other domain" />
```

This way, you can be sure your pages will not contain content from a non-secure protocol.

Comment: This is Really hacky... :)  Thanks Andy

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the popup that warns you of your page having both secure and non-secure elements?

If so the only way to solve it is to secure the non-secure parts, i.e. if you're linking to an image change the source from "http://www.testurl.com/image1.jpg" to be "https://www.testurl.com/image1.jpg". (Note the s on the end of the HTTP).

Finally if your problem is identifying the objects that are non-secure you can use an application such as Fiddler which will show objects requested by HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Thanx Colin for the Torch light on my problem :)